# How to remove numbers and Strings that occur together from a dataframe

Tags: regex, pandas

How I can eliminate the  alphabetic words from the dataframe

```
Text       Association
  12-43       KG,JK
  12g         MG,JK
  Main Road   
  12-45        JK,TG
  f12 
  Parallel     Road
```

**Current Code**

```
matrix = matrix[['Text', 'Association']]         
        import numpy as np
        conditions = [

           matrix ['Text'].isnumeric(),
        matrix ['Text'].str.len() == 1
        ]
        matrix  = matrix [~np.logical_or.reduce(conditions)]
```

**Desired  Output**

```
Text       Association
Main         Road
Parallel      Road
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need change:

```
matrix ['Text'].isnumeric(),
```

to [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with regex `\d` for match `number`:

```
matrix ['Text'].str.contains('\d'),
```

All together:

```
matrix = matrix[['Text', 'Association']]  

matrix['Text'] = matrix['Text'].astype(str)       

conditions = [

    matrix ['Text'].str.contains('\d'),
    matrix ['Text'].str.len() == 1
             ]
matrix  = matrix [~np.logical_or.reduce(conditions)]

print (matrix)
       Text Association
2      Main        Road
5  Parallel        Road
```

Comment: @jezreal, Should i Keep isnumeric also  if i want to remove  text that contains only ~number~

Comment: Then use `matrix ['Text'].astype(str).str.contains('\d'),`